# Is there anyway to tell what level is needed to open treasure chests in the Shifting Tombs other than attempting to open it?

Tags: runescape

Recently, a big update to Runescape introduced [Menaphos](https://runescape.wiki/w/Menaphos) (well, the ability to finally enter it after 12 years).  Within the city is the new Thieving minigame called the [Shifting Tombs](https://runescape.wiki/w/Shifting_Tombs).  One of the objectives in this minigame is to open all the treasure chests and loot them.  Now, in a solo game, the game scales to your level.  However, you can play this game with up to four other players (a total of 5).

When you play with other people, the scaling seems to change depending on the party.  Because of this, some of the chest appear to be set to a higher skill level than I am.  For example, one version of the chest requires you to use your Thieving skill.  Most of the time, it requires 99 (the maximum) to open it.  I am only a mere 81 Thieving so I cannot open it.  But the only way to know what level the chest is is to attempt to open it to which a message pops up saying "You need 99 Thieving to unlock this chest" or something to that tune.

Is there any way to tell what level is needed to open a chest besides attempting to open it? Trying to open it when you don't meet the level requirement wastes valuable time in this timed minigame.

Comment: I don't see why there would be... it's similar to Dungeoneering skill doors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think there is any other way to check. As @TerryA said in the comments, with dungeoneering skill doors, the only way to check what level it needs is to attempt to open it. Same with many things in the world of Runescape, the only way you'll ever know is to attempt it.

That being said, since you do have a lower thieving level, it might be wise to just save these chests for teammates you know have high enough levels to open them. That way you dont waste your time on opening chests and can do the other things in the minigame.